# -bash: .: filename argument required and .: usage: . filename [arguments] whenever opening new shell window (Kali Linux Rolling @ WSL)

Tags: bash, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Version

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.382]

#### WSL Version

- [X] WSL 2
- [ ] WSL 1

#### Kernel Version

5.15.57.1

#### Distro Version

Kali Linux Rolling

#### Other Software

*No response*

#### Repro Steps

#### On Windows PowerShell:

`wsl --update`
`wsl --install kali-linux`
[image]

#### On Kali Linux Window:

*After inputting new UNIX username and pass >>*

[image]

#### Expected Behavior

**The kali-linux distro is successfully installed and runs without any error message every time.**

#### Actual Behavior

#### Every time when a new kali-Linux window is opening:

[image]

#### Diagnostic Logs

#### Previously:

I was customizing zsh shell in kali. When I encountered some error messages and cant anyway get rid of those, I decided to remove the distro completely.

#### Using following steps:

1. Uninstalled Kali Linux from Apps
2. Open PowerShell

run: `wsl -l`

[image]

run: `wsl --unregister kali-linux`

[image]

run: `wsl -l`

[image]

#### Then:

I reinstalled the kali-linux again using `wsl --install kali-linux` command. And started facing this error.
I have tried again to uninstall and reinstall but the issue persists.

[image]

#### Temporary Solution:

When I delved more into this, I found out there is an error in `/etc/profile` file in the shell at a certain line. I could fix the issue by adding `$i` in a line after a `.`  as seen in other distros' same file.

[image]

The issue is solved temporarily, but further, down the road, it introduces more errors. For example, when I try to reset the Kali Linux app, it'd not reset back to its first state but would not run anymore. Then I would go into further error checking and go into solving the further issues.